# implications of unit normal vector

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Consider the following example

**Example.**  $\quad$ Consider the cylinder $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3; \ x^2+y^2 = 1\}$. We have that $\bar{N} = (x,y,0)$ and $N = (x,y,0)$ are unit normal vectors at $(x,y,z)$. We fix an orientation by choosing $N = (-x,-y,0)$ as the normal vector field. By considering a cure $(x(t), y(t),z(t))$ contained in the cylinder, that is, with $x^2(t) + y^2(t) = 1$, we are able to see that, along this curve, $N(t) = (-x(t),-y(t),0)$ and therefore
\begin{equation}
dN(x'(t), y'(t), z'(t)) = N'(t) = (-x'(t), -y'(t), 0 ) 
\end{equation}
So far, so good. Now, I'm having trouble with the following:

We can conclude the following: if $v$ is a vector tangent to the cylinder and parallel to the $z$ axis, then
\begin{equation}
dN(v) = 0 = 0v;
\end{equation}
if $w$ is a vector tangent to the cylinder and parallel to the $xy$ plane, then $dN(w) = -w$.

How are the last two implications derived? It seems easy, but I'm not sure how they derived/saw that the latter two hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $(a,b,c)$ on the cylinder. For any curve $c:[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\to \mathbb R^3$ on the cylinder such that $c(0)=(a,b,c)$ there is a vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in \mathbb R^3$ such that $c'(0)=v.$

We have $dN(v)=\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\gamma\frac{\partial}{\partial z},\ $ so

$dN(v)x=\alpha=v(x\circ N)=v(-x)=c'(0)(-x)=-c'(0)x=-\frac{d}{dt}(x\circ c)|_{t=0}=-v_1.$ Similarly, $\beta=-v_2$ and $\gamma =0.$

If $v$ is parallel to the $z$ axis, then $v_1=v_2=0$ and as $\gamma=0,$ we have $dN(v)=0.$

On the other hand, if $v$ is parallel to the $xy$ plane, then its $z$ component is zero so the calculation we just did shows that $dN(v)=-v.$